# pass dict by reference to bit encoded list of functions

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, pass-by-reference, python-multiprocessing

I seem to have an issue with a `Manager.dict()` that gets passed to a list of functions (within a sub process) as when I modify it within the function, the new value isn't available outside.
I create my list of functions like this:

```
gwfuncs = [reboot, flush_macs, flush_cache, new_gw, revert_gw, send_log]
gw_func_dict = dict((chr(2**i), gwfuncs[i]) for i in xrange(0,min(len(gwfuncs),8)))
```

and then call it like this:

```
for bit in gw_func_dict.keys():
    if gwupdate & ord(bit) == ord(bit):
        gw_func_dict[bit](fh, maclist)
```

Now assume we're talking about `flush_macs()`, whatever I do in the function to maclist, doesn't seem to be affecting the maclist outside of my function - why is this? How can I modify it the way that my changes are available outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` has higher [precedence](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `&`, so your `if` statement really acts like this:

```
if gwupdate & (ord(bit) == ord(bit)):
```

Add some parentheses and it'll work:

```
if (gwupdate & ord(bit)) == ord(bit):
```

Also, you can simplify your code a little:

```
gw_func_dict = dict((chr(2**i), func) for i, func in enumerate(gwfuncs[:8]))
```

And if you're using Python 2.7+:

```
gw_func_dict = {chr(2**i): func for i, func in enumerate(gwfuncs[:8])}
```

Also, iterating over a dictionary iterates over its keys by default, so you can remove `.keys()` from your `for` loop:

```
for bit in gw_func_dict:
```